# Python can't find CasADi on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm attempting to use the [CasADi library](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki/InstallationInstructions) on Linux in a python program but I keep receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EAF_Model.py", line 16, in <module>
    from casadi import *
  File "/vagrant/SRC_Local_Website/EAF_MODEL/python_plugins/casadi-py27-np1.9.1-v3.1.0-rc1/casadi/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from casadi import *
  File "/vagrant/SRC_Local_Website/EAF_MODEL/python_plugins/casadi-py27-np1.9.1-v3.1.0-rc1/casadi/casadi.py", line 21, in <module>
    _casadi = swig_import_helper()
  File "/vagrant/SRC_Local_Website/EAF_MODEL/python_plugins/casadi-py27-np1.9.1-v3.1.0-rc1/casadi/casadi.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_casadi')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _casadi
```

The code in my python file that is causing this error is below:

```
from sys import path
path.append(r"/vagrant/SRC_Local_Website/EAF_MODEL/python_plugins/casadi-py27-np1.9.1-v3.1.0-rc1")
from casadi import *
```

Unfortunately, I'm new to Linux, Python, and CasADi so I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong. I've attempted (and reattempted) to follow the instructions from the above link precisely but the error is always the same. I've also tried moving the folder around and using different paths (because I'm not sure if `/vagrant/SRC_Local_Website/EAF_MODEL/python_plugins/casadi-py27-np1.9.1-v3.1.0-rc1` is correct) but so far nothing has worked.

I've also attempted the same process on Windows and everything worked fine.

**Question: Why is Python unable to find CadADi?**

Comment: I wonder whether it needs building first. Did you follow the [InstallationInstructions](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki/InstallationInstructions)?

Comment: @PeterWood I'm not sure, but I did download the files from the "binary" section of the installation page, so I kind of assumed it has already been built.

Comment: Whereas below the section where I downloaded my files there is a "build from sources" section, which I did not use.

Answer (score 0):

for linux casadi can be easy installed with pip

`sudo pip install casadi`